# mySQL 'NOT IN' to vfp equivalent value

Tags: mysql, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I want to know whats VFP9 equivalent to mySQL 'NOT IN'.

To give you the exact purpose. I have two tables and I want to display all the numbers in table1 which don't have any occurrence in table2.

```
TABLE1
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10

TABLE 2
 2
 3
 4
 8
 9

RESULT:
 1
 5
 6
 7
 10
```

I have my mySQL code written:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.row1 NOT IN (SELECT row2 FROM table2)
```

Now this code wont run in vfp9, seem it did not recognize `NOT` or is there a flaw to my code. Any Idea.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: @TamarE.Granor - yes mySQL code is right but for some reason it still displays numbers from both tables. anyway got it with this code instead `SELECT t1.nvalue FROM release_numbers AS t1 LEFT JOIN customer_numbers AS t2 ON t1.nvalue = t2.nvalue  WHERE t2.nvalue is null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.row1 = t2.row2
WHERE t1.row1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 Right JOIN table2 on Table1.row1 = Table2.row2 WHERE Table1.row1 is not null
```

I believe your Table1 and Table2 is a cursor,

Comment: great...you know that im using cursor, i cant vote up since still little rep.

Answer (score 0):

Tamar's comment is correct. Try running the following code:

```
CREATE CURSOR table1 (row1 i)
CREATE CURSOR table2 (row2 i)
SELECT table1
FOR x=1 TO 10
    APPEND BLANK
    replace row1 WITH x
ENDFOR
SELECT table2
APPEND BLANK
replace row2 WITH 2
APPEND BLANK
replace row2 WITH 3
APPEND BLANK
replace row2 WITH 4
APPEND BLANK
replace row2 WITH 8
APPEND BLANK
replace row2 WITH 9
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.row1 NOT IN (SELECT row2 FROM table2)
```

It works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have created Table1 and Table2 with the exact same values as you.
I have executed             `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.row1 NOT IN (SELECT row2 FROM table2)`     
The result is 1 5 6 7 10.
The code is right, the result also.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.